# Price Slider and checkboxes in layered navigation magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want to show the price slider and checkboxes for other layered navigation menus. I was searching for a ready-made extension for the same. but I don't get any free extension for Magento 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

For any filtering needs I would highly recommend `Manadev Layered Navigation`, I know its not free but good modules will always come with some sort of price!

This module can be configured to do a wide array of filtering types such as checkboxes, sliders, radio buttons and dropdowns. It also has an AJAX option which is quite nice!

See url for more information: https://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus

Comment: Thank you so much but the problem is I have Theme in my project and Mana dev is not compatible with different themes sometimes. I need another extension

Comment: Did you create the theme or is it one you brought?